# InternalInsonsistencyException in ios sdk4.3

Tags: ios, ios4

Since I started using the IOS SDK4.3; not only have I experienced frequent crashes, I have also come across this very bad crash when I want to debug some apps:
Error Log:
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'MainWindow''"

I have once escaped this horror by selecting a lower iPhone simulator version, but not all the time.
What could actually cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, MainWindow.xib no longer exists in your project.